# Excel Data validation list on existing data

Tags: excel

I have a problem when setting up an excel data validation list on an existing table :
There are existing records that were filled before the addition of data validation list, and new ones that are added using the dropdown list.

The problem I have is that excel doesn't recognize some values as the same if they were from the existing table (that was created without the data validation list) and if they are created with the dropdown list :

Example : In my dropdown list, I have `Option A`, but when filtering on the column, Excel shows `Option A` `Option A` (one for the old data, one for the new).

The only fix i found to this is to manually select values from dropdownlist for old data to be considered as the same (but it is not a viable solution as there are too much to change).

Comment: What is forcing you to use the drop down list?  Why can't you use Ctrl H?

Comment: It's a file that is filled by other users, so using a list is a good way to ensure that the data they input is clean, problem is that its not coherent with previous data because excel recognise them as 2 different things

Comment: I know why data validation is used, my question is what is forcing you to click on the drop down box? Why can't you use Ctrl H?

Comment: I can, but I litteraly have to replace `abcde` string per `abcde`, and the searched string has to be copy pasted otherwise Excel does not find a match. Also there are a lot of options in the list (~80) so I was hoping for a more 'generic' solution

Comment: to add more info, if the column is copy pasted keeping values only, still there is a distinction between exact same strings when filtering. I have absolutely no idea what is causing this

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there were 'false' spaces (ASCII 160) which is why there was a difference between two seemingly exact strings.

Ctrl+H on the colum and replace Alt +160 per " " solved this.